# Printing field input data live with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-input

Got a question for you javascript gurus out there. I'm creating a sidebar tool that is comprised of a few different text input fields. The purpose of this tool is to edit copy on a template. I've tried to pass the data entered into the field onchange, but I'm running into problems dumping the data into my js object. This is somewhat what I have in mind:

```
$('myInputField').(function(){
      $(this).onChange(){
          // write to variable X
}
});
```

Essentially I want to have what I'm typing in the input be mimicked live and then I can parse the changes to my database.

Comment: `var x= $(this).val()` will populate the x with the value of input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't a simply keyup event on the input fields be sufficient?

jQuery:

```
$('textarea').keyup(function() {
    $('#foo').html($(this).val());
});​
```

HTML:

```
<textarea></textarea>
<div id="foo"></div>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/T4mX6/1/)**.

Comment: Perfect, everyone provided great examples, but I really like the usage of .html and .val in lieu of creating js variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#myInputField').(function(){
      $(this).onkeyup(){
          x = this.value;
      }
});
```

or more succinctly:

```
$('#myInputField').onkeyup(){
    x = this.value;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're just looking for the value that's in `myInputField` within that event handler?  Something like this?:

```
$('myInputField').(function(){
  $(this).onChange(){
      x = $(this).val();
  }
});
```

I don't remember off the top of my head if `this` is already a jQuery object.  If it is, then this should work and perhaps skip a little bit of overhead:

```
x = this.val();
```

Additionally, you can explicitly reference the field with a normal jQuery selector if `this` is ever overridden with a different context, or if you want to reference other fields as well, etc.:

```
x = $('myInputField').val();
```

Comment: `this` is not a jQuery object, which is why people use `$(this)` :). But you can use `var x = this.value`. Don't forget the `var` keyword otherwise your variable will be global.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: I guess I was assuming that `x` was defined elsewhere based on the question.  Good info to add, though!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, on IE, the `onchange` event doesn't work on INPUT elements. Thus, you have to use the `onkeypress` or the `onblur` event depending on what you want to do.

JS way:

```
document.getElementById('myInputField').onblur = function() {
    var x = this.value
}
```

jQuery way:

```
$('#myInputField').blur(function() {
    var x = this.value
})
```