# Display HTML with live form input field

Tags: javascript, form-fields

I'm wanting to have multiple input fields have a live output without having to hit submit and have the ability to copy/paste the output.

Ex:

```
<input id="name1">
<input id="name2">
```

IF name1 is not empty, then display: Hi name1

IF name1 and name2 is not empty, then display: Hi name and name2

I saw another post: [Printing field input data live with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076701/printing-field-input-data-live-with-javascript) that comes close to what I'm looking for but not quite.

This might be something simple but I'm struggling with it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can to handler it with javascript

```
// select element input
const input = document.querySelector('input');

// select element output
const log = document.getElementById('values');

// event listener invoke when something change in input
input.addEventListener('input', updateValue);

// method 
function updateValue(e) {
log.textContent = e.target.value;
}
```

more : [Run javascript after input is complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53402730/run-javascript-after-input-is-complete)

Comment: Thanks but I don't think that would give a live output while each field is filled out.

Comment: check the example:https://jsfiddle.net/dxqzfgrw/28/

Comment: Incredibly helpful! This is exactly what I was looking for. Will modify as needed but this is perfect. THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Alright so I tried modifying it. It worked initially with what you provided but once I tried tweaking it a bit, it no longer provided the output. Trying to integrate this with Gravity Forms on WordPress... I have the form created and want to replace the fields with the ones defined there.
https://jsfiddle.net/qLef5o84/